# UISearchBar:textDidChange: return value when empty?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uisearchbar

does anyone know how to test when the last character in a UISearchBar is deleted. i.e. you type ...

```
Gary > return "Gary"
Gar  > return "Gar"
Ga   > return "Ga"
G    > return "G"
     > return ???
```

.

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    [self FG_Filter:searchText];
}
```

I was thinking it would be @"" but I am having trouble getting that to work.

many thanks

Gary

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Actually, it returns `nil`. (Or at least it did when I wrote my `searchBar:textDidChange:`.)

But writing code that assumes that is probably foolish. Apple could change it to return `@""` next release. Instead, you're better off checking for what you actually care about: Is the field empty?

```
if ( [searchText length] == 0 ) {
    // string is empty
}
```

If you'd prefer not to change FG_Filter, something like this would be a safe change, too:

```
-(void)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar textDidChange:(NSString *)searchText {
    [self FG_Filter:searchText ?: @""];
}
```

Comment: You're welcome. I'm glad I could help! I remember the nil there surprised me, too...

Comment: I tried "if ([searchText length] == 0)" but it returned false. Because searchText returned "<object returned empty description>" when I wrote po searchText

Comment: You need to have a second look at the context around your test, Burak. `[nil length]` and `[@"" length]` both return 0.

Answer (score 0):

Put

```
- (BOOL)searchBar:(UISearchBar *)searchBar shouldChangeTextInRange:(NSRange)range
             replacementText:(NSString *)text
```

in your delegate and test if

```
[text length] == 0 && range.location == [searchBar.text length] - 1
```